# Can I have onClick() event for <h1> to <h6> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to have the `onClick()` event on `<h1>` to `<h6>` (any of the heading tags) for running some javascript. Please give me some example that has the `onClick()` event in an `<h1>` tag which shows some `alert()` message.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called the inline event registration model. And yes, you *can* do more or less what you're asking after.

***But please don't do this.***

It's ancient and reliable, yes. But the drawback is that it requires you to put your JS behaviors into your XHTML structure.

You are much better off using the following idiom:

```
element.onclick = doSomething;
```

In jQuery, this might look something like:

```
  $(":header").click(function(){
     alert('Handler for .click() called.')
   });
```

Good luck!

Comment: In general, something like this (or any of the other examples posted) is almost always preferable to registering behaviors and events within your HTML. It's much more maintainable.

Answer (score 10):

If you're willing to use jQuery, it's easy to handle.

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').click(function(){
    //do something on click
});
```

If you want a different function on each level of header, you can easily do that too:

```
$('h1').click(function(){
    //do something on click
});

$('h2').click(function(){
    //do something on click
});

//Etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a library like jQuery, here's one way to handle it:

```
var tags = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6'];

for( var i in tags ){
    var these = document.getElementsByTagName(tags[i]);
    if( these.length ){
        for( var n=0,m=these.length;n<m;n++ ){
          these[n].addEventListener('click',function(){ 
            alert('hello'); 
          },false);
        }  
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/HvvVQ/

As @Shadow Wizard points out in the comments, IE uses `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`, so to make this work in all browsers, you'll need some code that works both ways. If you want to avoid the rabbit hole of browser differences and verbosity, the same can be accomplished in jQuery like this, for example:

```
$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').click( function(){
  alert('hello');
});
```

Even more concise, thanks to @Kobi's comment, is `:header`:

```
$(':header').click( function(){...} );
```

I'd recommend going with a library of your choosing to make this sort of thing much easier.

Comment: You can also use [`:header`](http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/), which I don't think I ever found useful, until today.

Comment: the code does not work on IE which does not support addEventListener - cross browser code will be: `if (these[n].addEventListener) these[n].addEventListener('click', function() { alert('hello'); }, false); else if (these[n].attachEvent) these[n].attachEvent('onclick', function() { alert('hello'); });` here is the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/HvvVQ/1/

Comment: @Kobi, good one. That one never occurs to me. @Shadow, yep, it's no good for IE. I thought of throwing in the IE version as you correctly describe, but then figured I'd recommend the OP consider a library that abstracts away all that pain. I've amended the answer with better clarity on the IE issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
<script>
    function handleOnClick() {
    alert("Clicked on h1 tag");
  }
</script>

<h1 onclick="handleOnClick()">
  I am h1 tag
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'function' keyword to create function() and any code of logic comes inside the script tags.

```
<html>
        <head> 
            <title>Understanding Tags in JS </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1> Welcome to JavaScript Tutorial </h1>
            <h2 id = 'h2tag' onclick = "clickedMe()"> Click me to change </h2>
            <script>
                function clickedMe() {
                document.getElementById('h2tag').innerHTML = 'Alas ! I am clicked!'
            }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Add a description it would be helpful than a piece of code.