# Javascript onclick function not working on HTML heading

Tags: javascript, php

I want onclick to trigger when clicked on HTML heading as shown in code below.

```
<h2 class="title" onclick="viewPost('<?php echo $pageLink; ?>', '<?php echo $tabLink; ?>');">
<?php echo $menuItem["ContentMenu"]['title']; ?>
</h2>
```

My javascript function is as follows

```
<script>
function viewPost(pageLink,tabLink){
   //do something
    }
</script>
```

My problem is onclick works fine when it is in HTML link

```
<a href="#foo" onclick="viewPost('<?php echo $pageLink; ?>', '<?php echo $tabLink; ?>');" >
```

but it does not work in HTML heading. Please help.

Comment: Could you show the source rendered from that code?

Comment: <div id="online_subscriptions">
    <h2 class="title" onclick="viewPost('/ContentPages/view/1', '#online_subscriptions');">Online Subscriptions</h2>
    </div>

Comment: @nepalipunk - Why not use the Javascript debugger to check that `viewPost` is being called - I.e. place a breakpoint at the start of that function

Comment: @nepalipunk As far as I can tell, the source seems valid. Is there any error in the console? Can you validate that the function isin't getting called?

Comment: No error or warning in console. I found that function is not being called.

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked that the generated HTML/Javascript is valid. This works fine for me

```
<h1 onclick="alert('Hello');">A heading</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2S56N/ for a demo

Comment: That's not answer in my opinion.

Comment: It's a valid answer in my opinion. It's showing the minimum piece of code that illustrates the problem that the OP was having (something that the OP should have done himself instead of posting the PHP infested thing) and it proves that the "bug" doesn't appear when the function being called is one that is known to work. So the bug is proven to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Better use jquery than javascript, 
   [Can I have onClick() event for <h1> to <h6> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295679/can-i-have-onclick-event-for-h1-to-h6-tags)

```
$('h2').click(function(){
   //do something on click
});
```

and also I tried your code with some modifications(below) and it works fine

```
<script>
function viewPost(pageLink,tabLink){
alert(pageLink);
}
</script>
<?php
$tabLink = 1;
$pageLink = 2;
?>
<h2 class="title" onclick="viewPost('<?php echo $pageLink; ?>', '<?php echo $tabLink;     ?>');">click</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This I test it and its work fine:

```
<script>
function viewPost(pageLink,tabLink){
    alert("pageLink is" + pageLink +"tabLink is "+tabLink);
 }
</script>


<h2 class="title" onclick="viewPost('<?php echo 'testLink'; ?>', '<?php echo 'tabLink'; ?>');">
Click me
</h2>

<a href="#foo" onclick="viewPost('<?php echo 'testLink'; ?>', '<?php echo 'tabLink'; ?>');" > Click me</a>
```